# Hibernate: fetching objects collections without multiple bags

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

When I am trying to get list of my `Employee` entity I am getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch 
multiple bags
```

My `Employee` entity class has two lists of different objects. I suppose there is problem.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "employee_project",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id")})
protected List<Project> projects;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
protected List<EmployeeTheme> themes;
```

My entity `Project` doesn't have at this moment list of `Employee` objects. But

```
public class EmployeeTheme implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeTheme PK id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected Employee employee;
}
```

And this is my class for composite key:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeThemePK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    protected Long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "theme")
    protected String theme;
}
```

How can I properly configure these relations?

**EDIT**

I have switched List to Set for themes and projects. And I have excluded from my JSON themes and now I am getting another exception. I have also added `criteria.setFetchMode("projects", FetchMode.JOIN);` to method in my DAO class.

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.package.Employee.projects,
no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a 
collection of role: com.package.Employee.projects, no session or session 
was closed


Exception caught during request processing: flexjson.JSONException: Error 
trying to deepSerialize
flexjson.JSONException: Error trying to deepSerialize
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is triggered because you're getting employees and eagerly fetching the employee's themes and the employee's projects.

First, make sure you really really need both.

Second, realize that by doing it like this, you're making a cartesian product. If an employee has 100 projects and 100 themes, the query will return 10,000 rows just for this employee. Maybe you should fetch the employee with its projects first (100 rows), and then refetch the employee with its themes (100 rows again).

Third, if a cartesian product is really what you want, then make at least one of the collections a Set instead of a List.

Comment: How can we force Hibernate to feach, the data as you have described ?

Comment: Basically I need themes and projects to employees because I am creating JSON with employee list. And themes and projects of each employee should exist in my JSON. How can I perform actions from your second advice? First of all I need to use only Set?

Comment: Just do what I suggested: execute a first query that returns the employees with their projects. Execute the same query, but which fetches the employees with their themes. The seond query will populate the themes of the users already cached in the session. Or do a cartesian product, but then at least one of the lists must be transformed into a Set.

Comment: I have switched List to Set for themes and projects. And I have excluded from my JSON themes and now I am getting another exception. Please look at my updated question. Do you have some advices for me?

Comment: Try to simply display the results, without trying to deep serialize them to JSON. I wouldn't be surprised it's a problem with the serializer navigating to the bidirectional associations recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Hibernate.initialize()` in the DAO to fetch especific Atributes related with your main object, this avoid to load data probably you don`t need something like:

```
q = this.entityManager.createQuery('SQL..');
employee= q.getSingleResult();
Hibernate.initialize(employee.themes);
```